# Animation/Video as launch images ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, splash-screen, launch

Does anyone know if it's possible to show a video or an animation instead of a regular launch image in ios? The app's like D&G and Mango did this but I can't seem to find how. Is this maybe not an actual launch images, but a video which in triggered in the didfinishlauncingwithoptions.

Thnx!

Comment: I think that's exactly what it looks like to you :) they are probably using a blank screen for Default.png and launching a video in didfinishlauncingwithoptions as you presumed

Comment: Thanks... Was thinking this already. But just to be sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wel after the app hit the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions you can setup an animation.
There is no way to do this before this point.
The os just looks for the Default.png in the bundle and displays it als long as your app is starting up. (read not returned from the above mentions method).

Comment: Ok.. Wil try it like this then. Thank!